# Curl php blank result

Tags: php, curl, tiktok

I would like to display my tiktok profile page on my website by going through curl with php, I tried with one of my site it displays well but when I enter the link of my tiktok profile then it displays a blank page.

here is my php code

```
 <?php
    $url = "https://www.tiktok.com/@user_me";
    $ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Try to output an error: 
`$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === false) {
    var_dump(curl_error($ch));
}`

Comment: i try it gives no error only a blank page! and if in my original code I use var_dump on the result I get string0 ""

Comment: More than likely a site like that has protections in place to prevent such things. You should, first, check their TOS and then try curl options like CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, CURLOPT_USERAGENT (use a common one from a browser) and CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER.